# What does PLS stand for in PLS_INTEGER?

Tags: oracle, plsql

There's other data types in PL/SQL like BINARY_INTEGER. What does the PLS add in PLS_INTEGER? I was told that it stands for PL/SQL, but why would it be named that?

Comment: Did you read the spec? http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS003

Comment: @RemusRusanu The spec doesn't explain what PLS stands for, like the abbreviation.

Comment: I _assume_ it's an abbreviation for PL/SQL to distinguish it from an "SQL integer"

Comment: Why does it matter?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there is any deep rationale for using "PLS" in "PLS_INTEGER". When this datatype was added, it was a more efficient implementation of the "original" BINARY_INTEGER datatype. And a new name was needed.

Both of those types and other related subtypes have a constrained set of values compared to INTEGER. You can see this in the STANDARD package, in which the types are defined:

```
  subtype BINARY_INTEGER is INTEGER range '-2147483647'..2147483647;
  subtype NATURAL is BINARY_INTEGER range 0..2147483647;
  subtype NATURALN is NATURAL not null;
  subtype POSITIVE is BINARY_INTEGER range 1..2147483647;
  subtype POSITIVEN is POSITIVE not null;
  subtype SIGNTYPE is BINARY_INTEGER range '-1'..1;  -- for SIGN functions
  subtype pls_integer is binary_integer;
```